# What does the percent sign (% and %%) in a batch file argument mean?

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file, 7-zip

I think I'm missing something because I can't seem to find what this means.

Example:

```
for /D %%A in (*) do "\7za.exe" u -t7z -m9=LZMA2 "%%A.7z" "%%A"
```

That line was supposed to use a command line version of `7zip` to compress individual folders, but I'm stumped as to what `%%A` means in this context.

Comment: [What is the difference between % and %% in a cmd file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509652/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-a-cmd-file)

Comment: Got command line and bath file confused.  Changed the sign on top.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [`for`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/for.mspx?mfr=true) command needs a placeholder so you can pass along variables for use later in the query, we are telling it use the placeholder `%A`, the reason the code you saw uses `%%A` is because inside a batch file (which I assume is where you found this) the `%` has a special meaning, so you must do it twice `%%` so it gets turned in to a single `%` to be passed to the `for` command

To actually break apart what the command is doing, there is two parts to the command:

```
 for /D %%A in (*) do .....
```

What this part says is for every folder in the current folder execute the following command replacing `%%A` with the name of the currently processing folder.

```
..... "\7za.exe" u -t7z -m9=LZMA2 "%%A.7z" "%%A"
```

What this part says is execute the command `"\7za.exe" u -t7z -m9=LZMA2 "%%A.7z" "%%A"` and replace the two `%%A`'s with the current record we are processing.

Comment: Just to nitpick - the /D on the for loop will limit the * wildcard to directories, not "every file in this folder and every subfolder" (assuming Command Extensions are enabled).

Comment: @ernie you are correct, I was looking at the /R switch on the help page, I have corrected my answer.

Comment: Thank you for that, it shows how noobish this seems, but it's pretty archaic stuff that I have to dig through a couple online manuals for.

Answer (score 1):

It's a variable.

That particular example uses the [directory option of a FOR loop](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntfor.php), iterating through the directories and assigning them to %%A.

That's also not a command-line example, but a batch file example.  In batch files, you need to use %%A, while on the command-line, you'd just use %A.

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, the %%A is a placeholder for what the "for" loop is iterating over (which the /D indicates directories). So each iteration of the loop, %%A is one of the directories.

You'll see %% instead of % in batch code. You'll see % instead of %% used in your command prompt.

So know that if you copy over a batch file code into a command prompt and run it with %% being used, it will error, and vice versa.