# FOR/DO command gives "Was unexpected at this time" when run from command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line

Trying to run the following directly from the command prompt.

```
FOR /f "delims=[] tokens=2" %%a in ('ping %computername% -4 -n 1 ^| findstr "["') do (set ip=%%a)
```

While it runs fine from within a batch file, if run pasted directly into a command prompt, I get the following error:

```
%%a was unexpected at this time.
```

How do I need to change it to work directly from the command prompt and NOT require a batch file?

Long story requirements:

I have a requirement of basically providing a list of commands that can be run via copy/paste into a command prompt, WITHOUT using a batch file (just go with it, not my requirements but those given to me and can't be budged).  I have a later command that would echo %ip% to a .txt file.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When referencing For loop variable within a batch file you need to double up the percent signs (ie: `%%a`), but if you do this when just running the command straight at the prompt it won't work.  You need to change them to a single percent sign (`%a`).

Perhaps check out this other SU question for more info: [What does the percent sign (% and %%) in a batch file argument mean?](https://superuser.com/questions/670992/what-does-the-percent-sign-and-in-a-batch-file-argument-mean)

Comment: After a bit more testing, it appears you are correct.  I tried that and then just saw it print out everything after "DO" and didn't think it worked right, but I can then run an ECHO command afterwards and it works correctly.

Comment: This seemingly simple solution took me quite some time to find. Thank you for this.