# %%G was unexpected at this time

Tags: command-line

I have very little experience with CMD, and am trying to use it to call [a program](https://github.com/fzipp/gocyclo) on every `.go` file in a directory, recursively.

First, I was trying `for /R apiserver_sdk %%G in (*.go) DO gocyclo %%G`, but learned that doesn't work. Then, [heeding the advice here](https://superuser.com/questions/894475/for-do-command-gives-was-unexpected-at-this-time-when-run-from-command-prompt), I did `for /R apiserver_sdk %%G in (*.go) DO gocyclo %G`. In attempt to debug it, I changed `gocyclo` to `echo`, and wrapped the last `%%G` in double quotes, but still didn't work.

All attempts returned this error:

```
%%G was unexpected at this time.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FOR/DO command gives "Was unexpected at this time" when run from command prompt](https://superuser.com/questions/894475/for-do-command-gives-was-unexpected-at-this-time-when-run-from-command-prompt)

Answer (score 2):

OK, this is my fault for not reading [the manual](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html) more closely; /* I missed this line:

> %%parameter : A replaceable parameter:
>                    in a batch file use %%G (on the command line %G)

*/