# Batch file not running due to weird symbols at the start of the line

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, notepad++

I have a piece of code i am trying to execute in a batch file
it works fine when i run in in the command line but when i save it as a .bat file it fails with some weird symbols at the start of the line. This i think is related to the fact that the file type is UTF-8. I changed the encoding using notepad++ to ansi following the steps here from the thread [Weird characters (´╗┐) at the start of a batch file](https://superuser.com/questions/769601/weird-characters-%c2%b4-at-the-start-of-a-batch-file)

I tried to run the batch script now with the `ANSI` file format but it seems to ignore the PAUSE command so im unable to run the script or to trouble shoot it

Can anyone help

Script is

`for /r "K:\Folder_A" %f in (*) do @xcopy /Y/D "%f" "C:\Folder_C"`

Comment: Based on what you've provided, it might not be due to the encoding. Inside a batch file you need to use double `%%` instead of a single `%` when referencing variables.  See [What does the percent sign (% and %%) in a batch file argument mean?](http://superuser.com/questions/670992/what-does-the-percent-sign-and-in-a-batch-file-argument-mean)...

Comment: ...and an example of the same problem, from the other way around: [FOR/DO command gives “Was unexpected at this time” when run from command prompt](http://superuser.com/questions/894475/for-do-command-gives-was-unexpected-at-this-time-when-run-from-command-prompt)

Comment: yes :)...thats the answer. Would you please add it as an answer and il tick it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike when you run a For loop command at the command prompt, when referencing the variables within a batch file, you need to double up the percent signs (ie: `%%f`).

Perhaps check out this other SU question for more info: [What does the percent sign (% and %%) in a batch file argument mean?](https://superuser.com/questions/670992/what-does-the-percent-sign-and-in-a-batch-file-argument-mean)